# Power Automate - Select single item from Get Items

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, microsoft-flow

I'm trying to fetch an item from a list to perform some operations on (parsing JSON specifically) but when I use the `Get Items` action it returns an array, even if I select the top 1 from the results. The `Parse JSON` action can't take an array as input, only a single object. What can I do to prepare the item(s) in the `Get Items` action to be parsed?

Edit: Here's a screen cap of a simple workflow where I'm trying out this operation. When I try to Compose the People field from the Get Items action, it embeds it in a loop to go through the whole array of people. The problem is that I need to select one of those people and then make them available for the Parse JSON action to work its magic and let me access their DisplayName.
[image: sample image]

Also when trying to Parse a single instance of the People column, I get this error: "Invalid type. Expected Object but got Array."

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps that I would follow:

1. After [Get Items] action add a [Compose] action
2. Execute the Flow and examine the output from the [Compose].
3. Copy the output of the [Compose] into clipboard
4. Add [Parse JSON] action and use the output from step 3 as sample data to generate schema
5. Add addition actions like another [Compose] action to verify the Parse Data.
   Properties should be available from the Dynamic content.

To get a particular item's property, you can use the expression shown below.
Here [0] indicates the first item in the [Parse JSON] output, which is an array, and ['LastName'] is a list column (property).

```
body('Parse_JSON')?[0]['LastName']
```

[image]

Here is an [article](https://spmaestro.com/handling-json-in-microsoft-flow/)
describing how to work with JSON in Flow

Comment: I must be missing something here, every time I try to parse the output from the first compose action it throws the same error about being unable to parse an array.

Comment: What error messages are you getting? Is it something Null reference? If a property is defined as required in the JSON schema and Null values are returned by [Get Items], Parse JSON may fail. Please refer to [Article](https://spmaestro.com/handling-json-in-microsoft-flow/) showing how to correct the schema for Null values. Or Just test it with a simple one-two-column list first and then work with more complex list

Comment: The first issue is with the first Compose action. When I put the People field into its inputs, it embeds it in a loop because People gets returned as an array. When it's in that loop I can't access the People outside it. And even when I can, they're still in an array that Parse JSON won't handle. See my edit above.

Comment: See the screenshot that I've posted in my response - Add the [Value] or [Body] from the output of [Get Items] to the [Compose] action. Depending on what your are trying to do, [People] type can work as Input to [Compose].

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I wanted to suggest the action `Get Item` instead of `Get Items` if you only want one specific item, and you have the item ID.

The `Get Items` action **will** result in a loop even if you only have one item to retrieve from it.

If `Get Item` can't be an option, I'd suggest saving the item in an **Object variable** and working with that variable instead of the item property.

Comment: There is no "Get Item" in Power Automate that I'm aware of, only "Get Items"

Comment: There actually is, I use it a lot because it avoids the "Get Items" loop. [printscreen](https://prnt.sc/vuixg2)

Comment: We must have it disabled or something because it's just not showing up in my list of actions https://ibb.co/RC7VMHN

Comment: I usually search the actions so I haven't noticed this, but it's not close to the "Get Items" action. Please search near the end, above "Get list views" [image](https://prnt.sc/vukd20)

Answer (score 0):

1. Set Value to **1** for Top Count in **Get Items**

[Get Items > Top Count > 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd1tz.png)

2. Go to settings **Turn on pagination** and set value 1 to **Threshold field.**

[Settings > On Pagination > Value 1 for Threshold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6CWj.png)